# SVG image not getting updating on E11

Tags: javascript, svg, internet-explorer-11, elm

I have an accordion opens and close on click of down/up caret button. Works fine on all browsers except E11.

Through JS I am updating SVG's `xlink:href` attribute on click of caret like

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="accordion__trigger" viewBox="0 0 18 18"><path fill="currentColor" d="M 16.146 4.646 a 0.5 0.5 0 0 1 0.708 0.708 l -7.5 7.5 a 0.5 0.5 0 0 1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/assets/svg/sprite.svg#caret-up-1-18" /></svg>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="accordion_trigger" viewBox="0 0 18 18"><path fill="currentColor" d="M 16.146 4.646 a 0.5 0.5 0 0 1 0.708 0.708 l -7.5 7.5 a 0.5 0.5 0 0 1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/assets/svg/sprite.svg#caret-down-1-18" /></svg>
```

Inspecting DOM only `href` updated but not image in E11.

Is it because of sprite image with hash tagging not rendering in E11 ?

Not sure or its just a E11 itself or need to change toggle method for E11 only !!

Edited --

We replace SVG with Elm as

```
arrowUp : List (Svg.Attribute a) -> Html a
arrowUp =
    icon "arrow-up-18"

arrowDown : List (Svg.Attribute a) -> Html a
arrowDown =
    icon "arrow-Down-18"

up : Html a
Up =
    Icon.arrowUp iconAttributes

down : Html a
down =
    Icon.arrowDown iconAttributes

triggerToggle : Tag -> a -> Header -> Html a -> Html a
triggerToggle tag msg header icon =
    case header of
        Simple title ->
            trigger tag msg title [ icon ]

trigger tag msg title triggerChildren =
    div [ Tags.taggedWith tag, class "accordion__trigger", onClick msg ]

open tag msg title children =
    div [ class ("accordion accordion--open" ++ " " ++ mkClass title) ]
        [ triggerToggle tag msg title up ]
```

SVG sprite loads with page load and there is no console error .

Comment: updating SVG's xlink:href how? Please show us that code.

Comment: How do you update the SVG image? Is there any error in console in IE 11? Could you provide [a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can have a test and see how to help? We can't locate the issue with only the above description. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @RobertLongson There is no console error , update SVG image code updated

Comment: the fix here is to no longer support IE11, as god intended

Comment: I think i find sth over here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/117265/simple-svg-icon-not-displaying-in-ie11

Comment: Have you solved the issue according to the link you find? You could also refer to the answers in [this similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30127078/internet-explorer-draws-svg-incorrectly-when-updating-xlinkhref-for-a-use-ele). Besides, I tried to compile your elm code but it gets error. I think it lacks of `import` declarations or something else and is not a reproducible sample. It could be better you provide more codes related to the issue including html codes, scripts and so on.